# Adobe Premiere Pro - how to show multiple frames in timeline?

Tags: adobe-premiere, imovie

When I import video in iMovie, I can see multiple frames within the timeline.  This helps me to identify the slates where I can make cuts to separate scenes.  In Adobe Premiere Pro, I don't see any such frames.  Just one frame representing the full timeline.  Is there a way to make this behave like iMovie to show multiple frames within the same timeline BEFORE making the razor cuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - On the track layout, look top left where the name of the project is. Click those 3 horizontal bars. Go down and select "Continuous Video Thumbnails".
=)

Comment: Add more explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: This works perfectly!  That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you for taking the time to answer this question even after it went unanswered for months.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right menu entry to click. Make sure that the video track you want to see is "big" enough to visualize the thumbnails, otherwise they won't be visible.

[image: Continuous Video Thumbnails]

Comment: Good answer!  Thank you for the screenshot!